# Is it possible to get the output of only sudo command?

Tags: sudo, io-redirection

I want to write the output of only sudo command to some file i.e. the line which I get on terminal after writing sudo i.e.

```
[sudo] password for user:
```

If I use `sudo ls > file` or `sudo ls 2> file` then I get the stdout and stderr respectively of the whole command. Also I can't use `sudo > file` or `sudo 2> file`, then I will get error that I should use some options or command after sudo. So, is it possible to achieve?

Comment: For the avoidance of XY Problem solving, it seems prudent to ask why you'd want to capture this prompt from `sudo`

Comment: @roaima, that was just for knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sudo -S`, the `sudo` utility will write its prompt to standard error, and will read the password from standard input.  You can capture the output from standard error with `2>filename`.

Note that you still have to supply a command for `sudo` to execute and that the standard error of *this* command would also be redirected to the file, unless you do some file descriptor juggling:

```
sudo -C 4 -S sh -c 'ls non-existant 2>&3' 3>&2 2>sudo.stderr
```

This would redirect the output of *`sudo`* to `sudo.stderr` while still allowing the executed command to write to the original standard error stream.  We do this by opening file descriptor 3 as a copy of standard error, and then explicitly writing to this file descriptor in our command.  For this to work, we have to ask `sudo` to *not close* file descriptor 3 (which it would do by default).  This may require that an administrator has enabled the `closefrom_override` option in the `sudoers` file.

Note that there are likely subtle security concerns with the above command.